# Crontab every 3 days not working

Tags: linux, cron, debian

The last week I created a new crontab to do backups each three days and it didn't work.

This is the cron:

```
0 12 */3 * * /home/importante.sh
```

It's supposed to execute every three days at 12:00, but it didn't work for me.
Tried the script and is working fine, just the cron not executing it, any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crontab not executing bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218705/crontab-not-executing-bash-script)

Comment: Your cron entry looks fine. The problem is probably in your script and the differences between how it's executed (by you manually vs your cron).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Your cron will not run every 3 days.  It will run at noon every day of the month that is evenly divisible by 3.  Cron is not stateful and does not remember what day you started it.  In months that have more or less than 30 days you'll have times where your cron will run every 4 days (e.g. 31st,1st,2nd,3rd).

Answer (score 1):

Your cron entry looks fine. You are just missing the bash command.

```
0 12 */3 * * /bin/bash /home/importante.sh
```

I am assuming you are using bash. Just replace if it's different for you.